# Why bevel acts differently on half of the edges in symmetrical object

Tags: bevel

Now while learning blender I made a very simple light switch.
I want to make the four edges at front to be more rounded, so I use bevel instrument.
But for some reason it acts differently at different edges. Both variants don't suite me 100%, but at least top-left and bottom-right option I understand and also can easily fix to what I need. But I don't understand what is happening to the top-right and bottom-left edges.

Now, I've triple checked it and there are no duplicate edges or vertices or other mistakes I know of. It seems a perfectly clean symmetric mesh which I almost didn't touch. Faces seem to be ok too.
Please explain what is wrong. Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you've checked for double vertices.. are you sure the selection is identical on all corners? Are you bevelling edges or vertices?

Comment: I'm beveling edges. I've checked for double vertices. So no double edges possible if no double vertices. Yes, all looks identical, I've selected the individual edges and beveled it independently, the result is the same. :(